# Apps Script - Bookmark a Date Element on Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script

In general, I want to recreate the Insert>Bookmark on Google docs with a custom function upon bookmarking an element (all types of elements).

Now my issue is on bookmarking the Date element. I am getting

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRangeElements' of null

[image]

My current code for bookmarking Date element was something like this

````
selection.getRangeElements().forEach(e => {
  const elmnt = e.getElement();
  const type = elmnt.getType();

  if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.DATE ){
    bookmarked = doc.addBookmark( doc.newPosition(elmnt.asDate().getParent(), 1) )
  }

}); ```
````

Comment: Can you share the whole script you have? Would also be great if you can share copy/sample of your doc so we can replicate your process. Please remove sensitive data if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your showing script and your error message of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRangeElements' of null`, if `selection` is `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection()`, I'm worried that you might have run the script without selecting the smart chip of Date. Please confirm this again.
- And, in your script, `ele` is not declared. So, even when the error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRangeElements' of null` was resolved, an error occurs at `const type = ele.getType();`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

When you run this script, please select the smart chip of Date and run the script. By this, the smart chip of Date is added as the bookmark.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const selection = doc.getSelection();
  selection.getRangeElements().forEach(e => {
    const ele = e.getElement();
    const type = ele.getType();
    if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.DATE) {
      bookmarked = doc.addBookmark(doc.newPosition(ele.asDate().getParent(), 1));
    }
  });
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getSelection()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getselection)

Comment: Yes, I have selected it (click on it). From the screenshot above, there you can see that the date picker is visible.

Comment: @Pablo Thank you for replying. From `Yes, I have selected it (click on it). From the screenshot above, there you can see that the date picker is visible.`, when the smart chip of Date is selected and the modified script is run, I can confirm that the smart chip of Date is added as the bookmark. How about this?

Comment: it wasn't added as a bookmark as well. I can only bookmark the Date element if I select it through highlighting it.

Comment: @Pablo Thank you for replying. About `it wasn't added as a bookmark as well.`, I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I think that this is due to my very poor skill. I'm required to apologize for my very poor skill. In order to correctly replicate your current situation, can you provide the sample Google Document by including your current script? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: No need to apoogize, you're a big help. I don't know if you have read my edited reply (my reply before this). To let you know, I can bookmark the Date element if I select it through highlighting the element (but not on clicking the smart chip of the Date).

Comment: @Pablo Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm whether my understanding of your question is correct. From your showing script and your error message, I understand that you want to add the smart chip of Date by selecting the smart chip. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: @Pablo From Thank you for replying. `Yes that is right`, I understood that my understanding was correct. When you want to add the smart chip of Date by selecting the smart chip, I think that the reason of your current issue of your error message is due to that you doesn't select the texts. Please select the smart chip of Date and run the script.

Comment: I used the given script above. 
``` function myFunction() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const selection = doc.getSelection();
  selection.getRangeElements().forEach(e => {
    const ele = e.getElement();
    const type = ele.getType();
    if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.DATE) {
      bookmarked = doc.addBookmark(doc.newPosition(ele.asDate().getParent(), 1));
    }
  });
}```

I get an error of 
>TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRangeElements' of null

I confirm that I select the Date by selecting the smart chip.

Comment: @Pablo Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I run the script by selecting the smart chip of Date, the smart chip is added to the bookmark. I think that this is due to my very poor skill. I'm required to apologize for my very poor skill. In order to correctly replicate your current situation, can you provide the sample Google Document by including your current script? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247804/discussion-between-pablo-and-tanaike).